# bash: store/update text data

Tags: arrays, bash, list

so for reading the list of file, I use this code here below:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a data < ./somefolder/mytext.txt

for i in {0..9} #i know that i have 10 items, thats why i use 0..9
do
  echo "${data[$i]}"
done
```

lets say i have 1-10 in the txt file, so it should print like below:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Questions:

1. is there any simpler way to read/write the text list than this?
2. how to save/update/overwrite data of mytext.txt? lets say change 4 to 88 for example.

Full example:

```
#!bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a data < ./somefolder/mytext.txt

for i in {0..9} #i know that i have 10 items, thats why i use 0..9
do
  echo "${data[$i]}"
done

echo "change 4 to anything"

read any

update(){
  for n in {0..9}
  do
    if [[ n == 3 ]]; then
      echo any
    else
      echo "${data[$n]}"
    fi
  done
}

update > ./somefolder/mytext.txt
#i dont know what i should do, it throws some errors saying syntax error

echo "saved"

exit 0
```

Comment: Have you heard of [`awk`](https://likegeeks.com/awk-command/)? If you can create a more verbose example of what you're trying to achieve I can possibly create some test code for you.

Comment: Using `mapfile -t data < file`, you can read the file into an array, and with `printf '%s\n' "${data[@]}"` you can print its contents. Wrt your second question, you need to provide more details, and show us your research effort/failed attempts.

Comment: @Yaron i saw it a couple times, it seems confusing to me and i dont know what its for. it uses a lot of ^'`"$% sign when i saw one, makes my head dizzy.

Comment: @AhiungLim simply write a full example of what you're trying to achieve with several examples and I'll do it for you.

Comment: thanks @Jetchisel noted it

Comment: @Jetchisel

it prints like
`
foo
1 1
2 2
foo
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 10

`

Comment: Not on this side though, It increments the number by 1.

Comment: @Jetchisel [https://ctxt.io/2/AADA1olBEg] <-- output, expire in 1 day

Comment: my question should've been very clear already without providing any full detail, my intention is know how to save an output of echoes to a file. I just add it more complex for my future references, but...well I will just asking how to save an echo, thats it, forget anything else.
`echo "abc" | save this file command` how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code and output of the code, it is not the same as you describe in the comments.

```
printf '%s\n' {a..z} > file.txt
```

cat file.txt

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
```

A quick way of showing line numbers by using `grep`

```
grep -n . file.txt
```

A function to loop through an array.

```
func() { 
  n=1
  for f; do
    if (( n == 3 )); then
      printf '%d %s\n' "$n" foo
    else
      printf '%d %s\n' "$n" "$f"
    fi
    ((n++))
  done
}
```

```
mapfile -t array < file.txt
```

```
func "${array[@]}"
```

Output

```
1 a
2 b
3 foo
4 d
5 e
6 f
7 g
8 h
9 i
10 j
11 k
12 l
13 m
14 n
15 o
16 p
17 q
18 r
19 s
20 t
21 u
22 v
23 w
24 x
25 y
26 z
```

---

On the other hand if you just want to replace everything with anything at a certain line and and `ed` is acceptable/available.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf '%s\n' ,n | ed -s file.txt

read -rp 'Change 4 to anything: ' input

printf '%s\n' "4c" "$input" . ,n w | ed -s file.txt
```

---

A more flexible version of the previous script.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

total=$(printf '%s\n' '$=' | ed -s file.txt)

printf '%s\n' ,n | ed -s file.txt

read -rp 'Enter the line number you want to change: ' int 

if [[ $int == *[!0-9]* ]]; then
  printf >&2 '%s is not an int\n' "$int"
  exit 1
elif (( int > total )); then
  printf >&2 '%s is out of range!' "$int"
  exit 1
fi

read -rp "Enter the replacement at line $int: " input

printf '%s\n' "${int}c" "$input" . ,n w | ed -s file.txt
```

- Caveat The `file.txt` name and path is still hard coded to the script, just add an additional `read` for the the file.

Comment: yes, but this only `load` the text file then `process` the output, but not `saving/overwrite` it. so the content is still the same `a~z`.

Comment: `func "${array[@]}" > file.txt` should write to the file.

Comment: okay cool, see, very short right? doesn't have to get my post downvoted for chris sake. thank you @Jetchisel for saving my day.